# Why does integer division truncate only for positive numerators in python?

Tags: python, integer, division

Why does `integer` division truncate when `N // D --> N > 0` and `N < D` when N is positive, but doesn't when N is negative?

Example `12 // 25 = 0`

BUT `-12 // 25 = 1`

This is in python 3.

Comment: what language is this in?

Comment: Python 3, sorry for the confusion. Tunnel vision.

Comment: It's not truncating; it's flooring. (The operator is called "floor division" because it always floors, even for floats.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the answer here is that [Python's integer division floors](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) - it rounds down, always. So an instructive example would be something that doesn't yield 0, so it's more obvious:

```
>>> 10 // 3
3
>>> -10 // 3
-4
```

- 10/3 = 3.3333..., which rounds down to 3.
- -10/3 = -3.3333...., which rounds down to -4.

So, even if it's a positive fractional part, like `7 // 4`, which yields 1.75, Python rounds down to 1. The mathy explanation is in the linked blog post, this is just a mechanics explanation.